# How to call a MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i have a `MethodInfo` object, that defines a method i want to call.

Except i need the `object` that `MethodInfo` came from.

pseudo-code:

```
void CallMethod(MethodInfo m)
{
    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(m.ClassType);
    o.GetType().InvokeMember(m.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, null);
}
```

Except i don't know how to get the `type` of the class that `MethodInfo` belongs to.

How can i call a `MethodInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create an object from the type that your `MethodInfo` is, and will invoke it for you  on that new object.

```
void CallMethod(MethodInfo m)
{
    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(m.ReflectedType);
    m.Invoke(o, null);
}
```

Comment: Sample code that answers my question directly wins. But Reed's note in Jon's answer is important: `ReflectedType` over `DeclaringType`

Answer (score 5):

The `MethodInfo` doesn't *know* the target of the method call - the `MethodInfo` effectively belongs to the *type*, not one specific object.

You need to have an instance of the target type on which to call the method. You can find the type easily enough using `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` (inherited from [`MemberInfo.DeclaringType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx)), but you may not have an instance at that point...

As noted by Reed, [`MemberInfo.ReflectedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype.aspx) may be more appropriate than `DeclaringType`, depending on how you were planning to use it.

You haven't explained anything about what you're doing, but it may be more appropriate to take an `Action` delegate instead of a `MethodInfo`, if the rest of your design could be changed appropriately.

Comment: You may wish to mention that you don't need an instance if it's static.

Comment: Also - worth mentioning that the `ReflectedType` property *may* be more appropriate, since `DeclaringType` could be an abstract class...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Righto, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the type which defines the method by accessing the DeclaringType property of the MethodInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but it sounds like you're after a delegate rather than a MethodInfo.

```
void Main()
{
    Object myObject = new ArrayList();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = myObject.GetType().GetMethod("Clear");
    Delegate method = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), myObject, methodInfo, true);
    CallMethod(method);
}

void CallMethod(Delegate method)
{
    method.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

There's clearly an easier way to acquire the delegate in this circumstance (`method = new Action(myObject.Clear)`), but I'm going on your question of needing to use a MethodInfo object.

Comment: The `MethodInfo` comes from `Type.GetMethods` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf(v=VS.80).aspx), which is used to find all methods with a particular attribute.